# Reading from pdf - efficiency problem (R stat)

Tags: r

i'm willing to go through pdf files, get some info, add it to data frame and then write csv.
Everything works fine, but I've got efficiency issue. First 100 pdf files goes in 8 sec, wherease files from 1000 to 1100 are processessed in few minutes and it increases.

My code looks like:

```
#get list of files & set up data.frame:

files <- list.files(path=p_path, pattern="*.pdf", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

mydata <- data.frame("ID","type","value")
names(mydata) <-c("ID","type","value")

# loop thrugh files and read pdf:

for (i in (1:length(files)))
  {
  UC_text_source<-pdf_text(files[i]) %>% strsplit(split = "\n")  
  UC_text<- c(UC_text_source[[1]])

#for each file I extract some info, for example (:
  for (j in 1:length(UC_text))
    {

if (str_detect(UC_text[j],"School district"))
            {
            p_begin<-str_locate(UC_text[j],"School district")[2]+1
            p_end<-str_locate(UC_text[j],"\r")[1]-1
            p_schooldistrict<-str_trim(substr(UC_text[j],p_begin,p_end))
            mydata<-rbind(mydata,data.frame(ID=p_Ukey,type="Schoold_district",value=p_schooldistrict))
            }
    }
#Monitoring:
  if (isTRUE(i/100==round(i/100,0)))
  {
    print(Sys.time())
  }
}
```

I've got status monitoring in the first loop (every 100 files pring sys.time()). Processing time goes up. I thought about writing csv from data.frame every 1000 files and clear data.frame. it should help, but I'm curious which part of the code is causing the problem.

Comment: For longer loops seq_along() is much faster than length(). This might improve efficiency.

Comment: You would profit from using an apply loop instead. I or others could write one for you if you had provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Try to make your example easier and maybe use some publicly available PDFs to make an example that we can run. Maybe test with the [reprex package](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) before posting.

Comment: I think the problem is that I add rows to data.frame: mydata. 
I found here: https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/15-supp-loops-in-depth/
some golden rules for loops in R. There is sentence:
"Don’t grow objects (via c, cbind, etc) during the loop - R has to create a new object and copy across the information just to add a new element or row/column"

Comment: I changed the code using hints from this site:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/growing-objects-and-loop-memory-pre-allocation/
i.e.: I predefinied data.frame with fixed number of rows and columnd and than instead of using rbind I used 

mydata[row,]<-c(p_Ukey,"Schoold_district",p_schooldistrict)

Right nowe every 100 loops takes around 35sec. It's slower than first loops of my initial code, but efficiency is stable.